# Protect a folder from access

Tags: macos, catalina, desktop, file, malware

The folders: desktop, documents, downloads, network volumes and more are protected by Catalina.

Can I protect a folder in the same way as the one so that it is asked whether an application is allowed to access, for example, / usr / local /?

I am happy about every answer
Thanks in advance

Comment: Against which take of access/attack scenario do you want to protect these folders?

Comment: That applications cannot change anything in / usr / local and thus cannot do anything harmful (I installed my homebrew packages there), like the message "May Google Chrome access the desktop?"

Comment: As long as you aren't logged in as root Applications you run shouldn't be able to modify `/usr/local` anyway.

Comment: Homebrew has changed the rights from root to user. Homebrew doesn't allow you to run under root just to write in yourself.
On the other hand, I could save photos under / usr / local, which I don't want every application to be able to read.

Comment: It‘s probably better to put sensitive stuff into encrypted DMGs which you only mount when you need them. Anyway, please edit the question to describe your situation in more details. It also might help to not assume that the mechanism used to protect Documents may be the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer.
I will then pack my confidential content in encrypted dmgs. That would be settled then.
I still have to see how I do the binary files

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any method to apply the protection of ~/Documents etc to other directories.

If your primary objective is to protect access to a set of sensitive files it might be easier to create an encrypted DMG with Disk Utility and mount this only while you need to access these files.

Answer (score -1):

you could try

```
chown yourusername:yourusername /usr/local/*
```

Then

```
chmod 600 /usr/local/*
```

and any files in the /usr/local folder will be owned and only readable by you.

Im not sure i recommend this though.

Comment: If I specify the owner of a file on my name and block the access rights of everyone except me, then every application can still access this directory, since every non-root process always runs under my name by default, provided I am logged in under my account, everyone else Accounts are not allowed to access unless they are root, so it would be nonsense